# Display live wordcount in django wagtail backend

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm currently working with django wagtail CMS. how can i add word count for blog richtextfield in wagtail. What should i use for that here's some of my code from my models.py

```
class BlogPage(Page):
date = models.DateField("Post date")
intro = models.CharField(max_length=250)
body = RichTextField(blank=True)
```

my goal is to display word count for field body in the CMS backend

Comment: https://www.draft-js-plugins.com/plugin/counter https://vixdigital.github.io/draftail-plugins/

Comment: Great Thank you Very Much